# Data is not updating and showing empty in React native states

Tags: react-native

```
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator>
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}

const HomeScreen = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setCounter(counter => counter + 1)}>
                <Text>Increase</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}

const SettingsScreen = () => {
    return (
        <View>
            <Text>{counter}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Problem 1: i am using the above code in this counter is increasing. But i am not able to update it in the Settings screen as it just picked the start counter as 0. So not able to get how to update it.

Problem:2 if i am printing any state or array in the console. It is giving me empty []. But there is data in the state.

Problem :3 If i am moving from one tab to another tab. It is showing me sliding effect. I don't want to show this effect.

Answer (score 0):

try with this one

```
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setCounter((counter) => counter + 1)
      ? navigation.navigate('SettingsScreen', { number: counter })
      }>
        <Text>Increase</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const SettingsScreen = ({navigation,route}) => {
   const { number } = route.params;
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{number}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```